# Designing custom page template and reuse across sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

In my SharePoint online tenant, I have several communication sites, all of them are associated to a Hub site. I am designing a solution which should provide consistent layout for news pages, pages should also include custom properties and web parts.

For this I have created custom content type in content type hub, all news pages will use this content type. In one of the site I have included this content type in Pages library and designed a page by including custom page properties and webparts. Then I saved this page as template. I am able to create news posts using this template in this particular site.

But now I want to reuse this same page template in all other sites as well. There is no download and upload option in Pages library. Somehow I downloaded page template by PowerShell, but when I try to upload it in anther site by drag and drop, its not working.

Any thoughts how this can be achieved? How to provide consistent custom layout for news pages across modern sites?